# Getting HTTP - 403 Resposne, When sending tweet to twitter in iPhone. Why?

Tags: iphone, twitter, http-status-code-403

I have used Twitter+OAuth for iPhone [see the code in [GitHub]](https://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine).

I have signed in successfully and got Pin, access Token, Request Token etc. But when I am calling method `[_engine sendUpdate:@"Hi"]`, It is giving a `HTTP - 403` response and it fails to post in Twitter.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"twitter.com"
```

to

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"api.twitter.com/1"
```

in MGTwitterEngine.m

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API Wiki, there is everything you need to know...

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554652/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors